# Target dynamic classes with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a template that allows for multiple royalslider videos on a page (I don't embed the videos straight into the template because the client wants to use their own hi-res images as placeholders). I have a play button set up for each but when one is clicked, all play. How do I alter my jquery code to target each if i dynamically alter the class with php using an idx value (i.e. .myclass-0, .myclass-1, .myclass-2, etc.)?

```
<li class="gallery-item large-12 columns collapse royalSlider rsDefault vidImg">
<div class="vidLaunch">
    <div class="defer-image image-ratio:16x9">
        <div class="rsImg" src="[[+file_url:phpthumbof=`w=970&h=546&q=80&zc=1`]]" data-rsVideo="[[+url]]" alt="[[+name]]"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 $('.vidLaunch').click(function() {
    $('.royalSlider').royalSlider('playVideo');
});
```

Comment: Can you post some `html`? what type of element are `.myclass-0`, `.myclass-1` etc?

Comment: Does your dynamically generated buttons have these dynamic numbers like 0,1,2 somewhere in it? For example "data-refId=X" where X is one of the above number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for matching all elements having classes starting with `myclass-` (you will use the attribute selector):

```
$('[class^="myclass-"]').royalSlider("playVideo");
```

On the other side, you can append another class to these elements and select them like this:

```
$(".awesome-video").royalSlider("playVideo");
```

Comment: right. using php i can dynamically update the .royalslider class to .royalslider-1, .royalslider-2, .royalslider-3, per instance of the video, also .vidLaunch-1, .vidLaunch-2, .vidLaunch-3. I'm just looking for a way to tell jquery to find these dynamic pairings per each instance (does that make any sense?).

Comment: @pjldesign Exactly. This is what I answered: you can get the elements *having classes that start with `royalslider-`*: `$('[class^="royalslider-"]')`.